# Aggregate JavaScript files option is disabled

Tags: drupal-7

### Options below are disabled in our Drupal UI

- Aggregate and compress CSS files
- Aggregate JavaScript files

I'm new to Drupal and I need a direction where to look on that problem. We want to enable both options.

### our environemt is

- Drupal 7.2.3
- hosted on Amazon Linux AMI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directories probably have the wrong permissions set - go here admin/config/media/file-system to check your configuration and make them writeable.